# jquery Tablesorter - wont sort correctly if new option is selected from <select>

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

1) Table sorter parser to sort the drop down fields in the rows as they are when loaded on the page load, but if I try and edit any of the s then try sort the column again then it sorts by the original value and not the new value, can you help fix this?

2) If I try to select new value from the drop down option then click on the column header to sort then it doesn't work, why and do you know how to fix this?

My code now looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  return $("#tab1").tablesorter({
    widgets: ['zebra'],
    headers: {
      0: {
        sorter: 'inputs'
      }
    }
  });
});

$.tablesorter.addParser({
  id: "inputs",
  is: function(s) {
    return false;
  },
  format: function(s, table, cell, cellIndex) {
    var $c;
    $c = $(cell);
    if (!$c.hasClass("updateInput")) {
      $c.addClass("updateInput").bind("change", function() {
        return $(tab1e).trigger("updateCell", [cell, false]);
      });
    }
    return $c.find("option:selected").text();
  },
  type: "text"
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tablesorter caches the table data internally. When you change data, you must inform tablesorter that it should update its cache. Use

```
$("#tab1").trigger("update");
```

See the [appending table data with Ajax](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-ajax.html) on the table sorter homepage where this is shown.

Comment: I did this but.. I have two different tbody's within the same table. I want the table sorter only on the first tbody. Is there a way to use the skip the tablesorter for the second tbody???

Comment: @user1712810 I think you're using my fork of tablesorter, so just add a class name of `"tablesorter-infoOnly"` to the tbody ([docs](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/#cssinfoblock))

Comment: @Mottie Thanks a lot. That worked. It doesn't sort now but I still get the arrows in the table column headers. Is there a way to disable or hide the css headers for the tbody that doesn't sort???

Comment: Try adding this css `.tablesorter-infoOnly th { background-image: none; }`... just to make sure, only one `thead` is allowed per table, unless it is in a nested table.

Comment: @Tomalak Actually the parser is using `updateCell` which is an [undocumented method](http://wowmotty.blogspot.com/2011/06/jquery-tablesorter-missing-docs.html#methods) in tablesorter v2.0.5.

Comment: @Mottie I am using the table-sorter gem for rails. How can I add .tablesorter-infoOnly th { background-image: none; } to CSS file. Since I import the jquery-tablesorter directly from the gem. Is there any other way to do the same???

Comment: @user1712810 Sorry I don't know much about rails, but couldn't you add that to the default stylesheet? Maybe you could ask another stackoverflow question.

Comment: @Mottie i added it to the css. But Since my second tbody loads dynamically still the images are displayed. Is there any other way for it??

Comment: I think I'll need to see the code... can we continue this conversation via email so as not to pollute these comments? My gmail account username is wowmotty. Thanks.

Comment: Guys, maybe you should set up a chat or something. Interactive debugging in the comments of someone else's answer can't be the solution.